# How to make a text input editable every time it's clicked on?

Tags: react-native, redux

So I have a list of items and when you click on one it displays a modal with information about that item. I have a textbox to enter notes where I want to let the user enter notes. It successfully can save the notes the user types and shows the placeholder until they do, however, once I exit the modal and open it back up, it will display whatever was written the first time but you can no longer change it.

this is my text input within the modal (currItem is the item that is pressed to bring up the modal and takes the props)

```
<TextInput
   placeholder={'Add notes'}
   value={this.props.currItem.notes}
   multiline
   style={styles.notesInput}
   onChangeText={this.onNotesChange.bind(this)}
/>
```

My on notes change function:

```
onNotesChange(text) {
    this.props.notesChanged(text);
    console.log(this.props.currItem.notes);
  }
```

The action that is called from onNotesChange:

```
export const notesChanged = (text) => {
  return {
    type: CHANGE_NOTES,
    payload: text
  };
};
```

And the reducer that takes it in:

```
case CHANGE_NOTES:
      return {
        ...state,
        itmes: state.items.map(item => ((item.id === state.currItem.id)
          ? { ...item, notes: action.payload } : item))
      };
```

Also in the initial state of the item, the notes are stored as:

```
items: [...state.items, {
          id: state.items.length,
          text: action.text,
          notes: null,
        }]
```

On the redux side everything is working fine and what is stored in the state is being properly displayed. Again, the issue is that once I close the modal and open it back up it is no longer editable.

Comment: I am not very clear about your problem.But when the value is not null,the placeholder will not work.I think your code in placeholder is redundant.

Comment: Can you include the code for the `onChangeText` and how the data flows from there through the `currItem.notes` value that is being passed into the `TextInput`'s `value` prop?

Comment: yes I will do that now, my apologies for the late response